# Import Google API JSON file to Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, google-api, elastic-stack, google-admin-sdk

I'm totally new with ELK stack and especially with ES.
I'm trying to import a JSON file which I got using Google Admin SDK API and I want to import it to Elasticsearch.

So far this is the JSON structure of my data:

```
{
"kind": "reports#activities",
"nextPageToken": string,
"items": [
{
"kind": "audit#activity",
  "id": {
    "time": datetime,
    "uniqueQualifier": long,
    "applicationName": string,
    "customerId": string
  },
  "actor": {
    "callerType": string,
    "email": string,
    "profileId": long,
    "key": string
  },
  "ownerDomain": string,
  "ipAddress": string,
  "events": [
    {
      "type": string,
      "name": string,
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": string,
          "value": string,
          "intValue": long,
          "boolValue": boolean
        }
       ]
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

So I decided to first use this command to upload the JSON file into ES :

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @documents.json
```

But I get some errors :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [START_ARRAY]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [START_ARRAY]"},"status":400}
```

What should I do ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JSON seems to be defining your document structure, so you first need to create an index with a mapping that will match that structure. In your case, you could do it like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/reports -d '{
  "nextPageToken": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "items": {
    "properties": {
      "kind": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "properties": {
          "time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_time"
          },
          "uniqueQualifier": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "applicationName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "customerId": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "actor": {
        "properties": {
          "callerType": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "profileId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "key": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "ownerDomain": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "ipAddress": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "events": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "parameters": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "intValue": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "boolValue": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This being done, you can now index your `reports#activities` documents that follow the above structure using a bulk call. The syntax of bulk calls is precisely defined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), i.e. you need a command line (what to do) followed on the next line by the document source (what to index) which must not contain any new lines!

So, you need to reformat your `documents.json` file like this (make sure to add a new line after the second line). Also note that I've added some dummy data to illustrate the process:

```
{"index": {"_index": "reports", "_type": "activity"}}
{"kind":"reports#activities","nextPageToken":"string","items":[{"kind":"audit#activity","id":{"time":"2016-05-31T00:00:00.000Z","uniqueQualifier":1,"applicationName":"string","customerId":"string"},"actor":{"callerType":"string","email":"string","profileId":1,"key":"string"},"ownerDomain":"string","ipAddress":"string","events":[{"type":"string","name":"string","parameters":[{"name":"string","value":"string","intValue":1,"boolValue":true}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Val ! Actually my JSON data contains arrays (items[], events[] and parameters[]) so I slightly edited your code regarding the index creation by replacing some braces into brackets and It worked !

Comment: No you shouldn't, that was done on purpose, ES will create those arrays for you ;) See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)